# My code does not do what i want column by column on visualbasic

Tags: excel, vba

I have this VBA code in Excel. What it does is, if in a certain column of the 'sinkominutalez' sheet, there are consecutive zero values that occur more than 3 times in a row, the code extracts the value from the second row of the column where consecutive zeros are found (which is the ID of the device with zero values). Then, it extracts the value from column A in the row where the first zero is found (column A contains date and time), and places it in the second column of the 'resultados' sheet. Finally, it places the value from column A where a non-zero value starts after the consecutive zeros in the 'resultados' sheet.

My problem is that I want the code to treat zero values independently in each column, meaning there are certain columns that have zero values all the way to the end, and in that case, it should put a) the value from the second row of the next column with zeros, and b) times (i.e., the values in column A) with values different from what I want.

Example of sheet zinkominutales

[image]

Example where if a column ends on 0's it puts the ID of the device of the next column and different values of hour and date. I want it to be on sheet "resultados"

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Inv 13.3 | 01/11/22 7:15 | 01/11/22 18:15 |

[image]

I've done this

```
Sub EncontrarRangosCero()
Dim ws1 As Worksheet  'sinkominutalez
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet ' resultados
    Dim countZeros As Integer
    Dim i As Long, j As Long 'i para filas y j para columnas
    Dim lastRow As Long 
    
    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sinkominutalez")
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("resultados")
    
    
    countZeros = 0
    lastRow = ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    ' Recorrer todas las columnas
    For j = 1 To ws1.UsedRange.Columns.Count
        For i = 90 To 222
            If ws1.Cells(i, j).Value = 0 Then
                If countZeros = 0 Then
                    ' Guardar la fila donde comienza el rango de ceros
                    startRow = i
                End If
                countZeros = countZeros + 1
            ElseIf countZeros > 0 Then
                endRow = i - 1 ' Guardar la fila donde termina el rango de ceros
                ' Si el rango de ceros tiene más de 3 celdas, escribir los valores en Hoja2
                If countZeros > 4 Then
                    ' 
                    ws2.Cells(lastRow, 1).Value = ws1.Cells(2, j).Value
                    ws2.Cells(lastRow, 2).Value = ws1.Cells(startRow, "A").Value
                    ws2.Cells(lastRow, 3).Value = ws1.Cells(endRow + 1, "A").Value
                    lastRow = lastRow + 1
                End If
                countZeros = 0
            End If
        Next i
    Next j
End Sub
```

Also, there are certain columns that have 0 consecutive values, then it stops and then 0 values again, i want to write the hour where each range of value starts and stops.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT1**: fixed line
   `ws2.Cells(lastRow, 2).Value = ws1.Cells(i, "A").Value`
corrected to:
   `ws2.Cells(lastRow, 2).Value = ws1.Cells(startRow, "A").Value`

Try this out:

```vb
Sub EncontrarRangosCero()
    
    Const LAST_ROW As Long = 222
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet  'sinkominutalez
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet ' resultados
    Dim countZeros As Long, startRow As Long
    Dim i As Long, j As Long 'i para filas y j para columnas
    Dim lastRow As Long, v
    
    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sinkominutalez")
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("resultados")
    
    For j = 1 To ws1.UsedRange.Columns.Count 'should start at >1 ???
        countZeros = 0
        
        For i = 90 To LAST_ROW
            v = ws1.Cells(i, j).Value
            If Len(v) > 0 Then  'cell has content?
                If v = 0 Then
                    If countZeros = 0 Then startRow = i
                    countZeros = countZeros + 1
                    If countZeros = 3 Then
                        lastRow = ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                        ws2.Cells(lastRow, 1).Value = ws1.Cells(2, j).Value
                        ws2.Cells(lastRow, 2).Value = ws1.Cells(startRow, "A").Value  ###edit1
                    End If
                    'handle case where zeros go to the end of the column
                    If i = LAST_ROW Then ws2.Cells(lastRow, 3).Value = ws1.Cells(i, "A").Value
                Else
                    If countZeros >= 3 Then
                        ws2.Cells(lastRow, 3).Value = ws1.Cells(i - 1, "A").Value
                    End If
                    countZeros = 0
                End If
            End If  'cell has a value
        Next i      'next row
    Next j          'next column
End Sub
```